# Counterexamples in model categories

Tags: homotopy-theory, model-categories

Can it happen that a model category has factorisations which can not be made functorial, but still it admits a (co)fibrant replacement functor?

Comment: If you have functorial factorisations you certainly also get a (co)fibrant replacement functor. The fact you want is the contrapositive, but you ask about the converse.

Comment: @ZhenLin You are right, I got confused. I would like to know about the converse